# How to Return to a previous step in a C program upon user input?

Tags: c, loops, switch-statement, do-while

I want go back to the previous step when user input is invalid. i already given 3 options to select in Dates. when user input another number except 1,2,3 i want to display something like "invalid input. press 1 to go back to previous step press 9 to exit". please help

```
            1. while(l != 9){
                            2. printf("\n select a date : \n");
            3. dates();
            4. printf("Date : ");
            5. scanf("%d", &date);
            6. printf("\n select a theatre : \n");
            7. theatre();
            8. printf("\n theater : ");
            9. scanf("%d", &thter);
            10. if(thter==1){
```

Comment: You can put the input request into a loop, which you repeat until the input is acceptable.

Comment: C and C++ are very different languages. Don't tag both unless you're asking specifically about their differences.

Comment: Maybe a `goto` statement would be good here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_goto_statement.htm

Comment: @Sahani Randula - Why do you want to bother the user with entering 1 before he gets to retry the input? Better give him the option "9 to exit" in the first place.

Comment: `scanf` is notoriously difficult to use correctly, but if you insist on using it, you *must* check its return value.  Be aware that if `scanf` returns 0, there is a very good chance that no data has been consumed, so if you loop you may continuously re-read (and reject) the same input.   In other words, you cannot simply do `while(scanf(...) != 1)` without having something in the loop body that consumes at least one char.  My suggestion is: don't use scanf.

Comment: thank you everyone. all the answers were really helpfull